# Oracle | "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" in with-clause

Tags: oracle, subquery, with-clause

I need to write a query as below - query given is just for concept.

I am getting `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` for view table `inner_nested_table` used in `with` clause.

First, is it legal to use it like this? If no, is there any work-around I can use.

```
select
    inner_nested_table.column1,
    inner_nested_table.column2,
    inner_nested_table.column3,
    (
        with test as (
            select
                column4, column5
            from
                inner_nested_table
        )
        select column4 from test
    ) columnX
from
    (
    select
        column1,
        column2,
        column3,
        column4,
        column5
    from
        actual_table
    ) inner_nested_table;
```

Comment: `WITH test` then `SELECT columns4 from temp` You want `test` not `temp`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: It's not the `with` clause; as MTO said it's a level issue, and it breaks with a nested inline view too - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c9ac60582a732f8f70f04baf7fb76eed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` sub-query is nested too deeply for the SQL engine to find the `inner_nested_table`. Oracle supports finding aliases nested one level apart but not two.

Instead, you can use:

```sql
WITH inner_nested_table AS (
  select column1,
         column2,
         column3,
         column4,
         column5
  from   actual_table
),
test AS (
  select column4
  from   inner_nested_table
)
select column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       (select column4 from test) AS columnX
from   inner_nested_table;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=78178b2657a10ee183a7d896e444e5b1)*